# C# Unlock file used by running process

Tags: c#, .net

I am attempting to change an existing file stream from within C#. The process that holds the stream is outside of my control and I cannot view or access it's code.

The file stream is opened in a read/write state with a lock preventing file share. I am attempting to alter the stream state *in place without closing it*, as closing the handle of the stream immediately causes the process to crash.

No alternative methods are possible, the original file needs to be accessed; not a copy. Altering the permissions on the file has no effect on the lock. Pausing the process, closing the handle and attempting to recreate it with the same handle id does not seem to be working, as the program does not seem to accept the handle and simply closes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I edited for clarity on this, but it boils down to: no. I am simply trying to unlock a file for read only access instead of locked for read/write. I am not even trying to interact with the file beyond that.

Comment: How does the game determine that another instance exists? Does it test for mutex existence or does it attempt to set/enter the mutex? If it's the latter you might be able to just reset it. Possibly change mutex security to disallow everything.

Comment: The mutex itself isn't a problem. It's a named mutex and I am already able to remove it. It's the file lock that is a problem. I assume it is opened with the equivalent of FileStream("file.ext", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None), however I don't even know the language of the client.

Comment: @KairuByte you should [edit] your post and add actual question from your comment. I've read the post several times and can't see how it is related to you comment. While editing make sure there is no "edit:" blocks... Removing 90% of background information may be useful too.. Side note: I'm quite sure what you are trying to do (make other process to open file in different mode) is not possible without finishing you custom file system solution (or any other method that virtualizes file access).. C# is not a good too for it... Also read "Windows internals" book.

Comment: Edited, an I can see why you suggested it. I tend to over talk. I'll definitely see if I can find something to read up on Windows Internals. The problem with my previous solution is that I don't want the user to have to install something that deep and run all the time. If that is the only solution I will likely abandon the idea. I'll keep looking though!

Comment: Maybe close the file handle by force and start creating dummy file handles until you have created one that matches the value of the handle you destroyed. Windows seems to reuse handle values a lot. This is probabilistic but might almost always work.

Comment: The moment the file handle is closed the application crashes, no time to attempt that unfortunately.

Comment: Could you determine why it crashes? Was it waiting on the handle? I don't know what waiting on a file means. If it's not waiting but racy you could suspend all threads and perform the switch then.

Comment: the only way I know, to release a file which is being "held" by another process, is to either kill the process or forcefully close the handle itself. the latter will probably make the process unstable.  if CHANGING the handle rights is possible i'd love to see how. use sysinternal's Procmon.exe (process monitor) to see why the process crashes, but i wouldn't get my hopes up.

Comment: procmon gives a lot of info I'll have to sort through later. Thank you for pointing me in a direction!

Comment: Shadow copy and a system restore point may work for you depending on your frequency of needing access to the locked file.

Comment: The locked file will be accessed almost constantly while in use. And by one to many (dependent on system resources) applications.

Comment: If you want to change from WRITE to READ, why not make it read-only to begin with, and then remove it when WRITE is needed ? sure it won't be 100% and you'll probably have to worry about the access-race between processes but then again, i can't see any stable approach to this really.

Comment: I've seen a stable version once, however that was years ago and the Dev didn't reply to communication attempts. Unfortunately the writing isn't the problem, the file is still opened with a locked share mode.

Comment: Obviously, this does not make sense at all what you are trying to do as lock are designed to prevent access by another process to the region that is locked. You have to design both application so that they don't always keep the file locked.

Comment: I don't have the ability to change the design of the second app. And I have seen this work before in a closed source application, where it was able to alter the state of the file lock in an external application. In this case the entire file is opened in a mode that prevents sharing, however as long as specific conditions are met the file is not written to for the duration of this lock. I can check that those conditions are met, but I need to alter the lock after I am sure they are met.

Answer (score 0):

If you want readonly access to a file from multiple processes, consider just copying the file for each process. That replaces the need to change the file handle with 3 potentially simpler problems:

1. Before a process runs, produce a copy of the file for it to consume.
2. Direct the process to consume that copy (ex. through a commandline arg).
3. After the process is finished executing, delete the copy.

Comment: The problems vary in difficulty here. The main one being that the file itself is actually at least 26GB in size, and at most over 32GB.

Comment: Oh... Please add that gotcha to your question.

Comment: I was about to suggest that but there are to many pitfalls to this, so even if its "just" 100mb file, and its located on network drive (For shared use I assume) this won't be pretty. the question is in it's spot, in theory it should be possible, code-wise, i'd love to see it.

Comment: I have actually seen it done before, but it was not open source and the dev never responded to my attempts at communication.